# Enable, Disable Panel in parent from child form

Tags: c#, windows, panel, show-hide, dashboard

I am developing C# windows application. My DASHBOARD look like PICTURE-1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhztH.jpg)

But, when I clicked sub menu sub menu shows like PICTURE-2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIm63.jpg)

Sub menu must show like PICTURE-3. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbaJi.jpg)

I have disabled panel at the time of loading of sub menu. I have tried to load DISABLED PANEL FROM SUBMENU, when submenu closed button is clicked. But the problem is other summery panel is not loaded in CONTAINER PANEL. It looks like PICTURE-4.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJHJc.jpg)

I have done following things:
1. Set all panels modifiers to PUBLIC.
2. I have created a object in submenu form.
3. After that I tried to call all container and set the property of that panel as enable.
4. I have tried SHOW(), SHOWDIALOGUE(). But another form is loaded in taskbar.

My code is for calling SUBMENU from MAIN MENU (DASHBOARD) is

```
private void btnAdminDataBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
panelMainMenuRight.Visible = false;
panelTopSummery.Visible = false;
panelRightSummery.Visible = false;
submenuAdmin.Visible = false;
MenuDisplay(new Forms.frmDataBackup());
}

private void MenuDisplay(object MenuName)
{
Form fh = MenuName as Form;
fh.TopLevel = false;
fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.panelContainer.Controls.Add(fh);
this.panelContainer.Tag = fh;
fh.Show();
}
```

Code is from SUBMENU:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Main_Menu mnu = new Main_Menu();
mnu.panelContainer.Visible = true;
mnu.panelMainMenuRight.Visible = true;
mnu.panelRightSummery.Visible = true;
mnu.panelTopSummery.Visible = true;
this.Close();
}
```

You are requested to help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.